# Add degrees of freedom (df or df.error) to the output of model tables with modelsummary

Tags: r, modelsummary

I'm fitting a list of models and generating tables of the results with [modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html). Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(modelsummary)

m_test <- list(
  lm(bill_length_mm ~ flipper_length_mm, data = penguins),
  lm(bill_length_mm ~ flipper_length_mm + body_mass_g, data = penguins))

modelsummary(m_test)
```

The default `modelsummary` table prints estimated coefficients and intercepts with standard errors, as well as the number of observations, AIC, BIC, F, RMSE, R2, and R2 Adj. However, I also want this table to print degrees of freedom for each model. I tried `modelsummary(..., metrics="all",...)` and `modelsummary(..., metrics=c("R2","AIC","df.error",...)` (with various names for DF like "df.residual") but none of those worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the available goodness-of-fit statistics are the columns in the output of the `get_gof()` function:

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(modelsummary)

mod <- lm(bill_length_mm ~ flipper_length_mm, data = penguins)

get_gof(mod)
#>        aic      bic r.squared adj.r.squared     rmse nobs        F
#> 1 1943.966 1955.471  0.430574     0.4288992 4.113792  342 257.0925
#>   Degrees of Freedom
#> 1                340
```

There is already a good answer here, which suggests that you manipulate a `modelsummary_list` object. Another option is to defined a `glance_custom.lm` function that adds the quantity you want. The benefit of this approach is that you define the function once, and the quantity will then automatically be added for subsequent models.

In this example, I use the `get_df` function from the `insight` package to extract the degrees of freedom:

```r
glance_custom.lm <- function(x, ...) {
    data.frame(
       `Degrees of Freedom` = as.character(insight::get_df(x)),
       check.names = FALSE)
}

mod <- list(
   lm(bill_length_mm ~ flipper_length_mm, data = penguins),
   lm(bill_length_mm ~ flipper_length_mm + body_mass_g, data = penguins))
modelsummary(mod, "markdown")
```

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | -7.265 | -3.437 |
|  | (3.200) | (4.581) |
| flipper_length_mm | 0.255 | 0.222 |
|  | (0.016) | (0.032) |
| body_mass_g |  | 0.001 |
|  |  | (0.001) |
| Num.Obs. | 342 | 342 |
| R2 | 0.431 | 0.433 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.429 | 0.430 |
| AIC | 1944.0 | 1944.6 |
| BIC | 1955.5 | 1959.9 |
| F | 257.092 | 129.365 |
| RMSE | 4.11 | 4.11 |
| Degrees of Freedom | 340 | 339 |

You'll find detailed documentation on this strategy on the website: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this lies in [this help file for modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#customizing-existing-models-part-iii). The code below modifies the modelsummary list object so that what gets printed includes `df.error`. The trick was figuring out that the desired variable was `df.error` and that it lives inside of `tidy` but the only way I could get it to print was by assigning it to `glance`. There may be a less hacky solution, but this worked for me.

For a single model:

```
m_simple <- modelsummary(list(
  lm(bill_length_mm ~ flipper_length_mm, data = penguins)),
  output = "modelsummary_list"
)

m_simple$glance$df.error <- m_simple$tidy$df.error[1] # IMPORTANT: you should visually inspect this to be sure it's the metric of df you want! 
modelsummary(m_simple)
```

And for a list of models:

```
m_prep <- modelsummary(list(
  lm(bill_length_mm ~ flipper_length_mm, data = penguins),
  lm(bill_length_mm ~ flipper_length_mm + body_mass_g, data = penguins)
),output = "modelsummary_list" )
  
m_out <- as.list(m_prep)
for(i in 1:length(m_out)){
  m_out[[i]]$glance$df.error <- m_out[[i]]$tidy$df.error[1]
}

modelsummary(m_out)
```

Note that this can easily print the wrong metric if you don't personally check for your models that the first element in the `df.error` list is the one that you want.